Is sacrifice an inherent human desire?
In chapter 4 of the Book of Genesis, Cain is written to have killed his brother Abel out of jealousy over the difference in their offerings to God. Cain was bestowed the role of a tiller of the ground, while Abel was a keeper of sheep.
"In the course of time, Cain brought to the LORD an offering of the fruit of the ground,
and Abel for his part brought of the firstlings of his flock, their fat portions. And the LORD had regard for Abel and his offering,
but for Cain and his offering he had no regard. So Cain was very angry, and his countenance fell."
At this time in the creation story, there were only about four people on earth who did also not have a bible or societal customs for sacrifice or any sort of offerings. Adam and Eve were also aware that they had to make sacrifices for the sake of God, but why? God is never mentioned to have instructed them to make offerings to him (which doesn't make very much sense to me anyway), but they still do. Was it something already instinctual in them as people? Is it an inherent human desire to make sacrifices to God?

It was God himself who set the example by providing skins to clothe the man and the woman. Thus, death and bloodshed. Abel followed that example. Cain did not.

@NigelJ Please don't think that I am defending those actions at all, I just don't really understand why God would happily accept Abels offering and so outwardly deny Cains. If those were the places they were assigned, why wasn't Cain fulfilling the role God gave him good enough?

@sofi You didn't ask about the difference between the offerings. I could go into that as well... perhaps make a new question? Because there is more then just what I answered with because I tried to stay on topic. :) I find Nigel's quick response extremely abbreviated, which does not give good context for the content. It is much more then just "Abel followed a bloodshed/death example that God gave" Cain was sinful before and after the Sacrifice. Abel was trying to not be sinful. Even if they didn't have firm instructions on that subject.

Curiously, The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints has an explanation of why Adam and Eve sacrificed (they were instructed by God) in our Book of Moses. Whether you wish to respect that or not, the point is that it's a challenge to assume that scriptural records inspired by God but written by mortals have every bit of every story and no more. Frankly, given that scripture teaches that the "natural man" is an enemy to God, it's far more likely that human nature is to be selfish than to sacrifice.

I can offer a more abstract explanation in the sense that there is a mythological approach that easily explains it. Some context also helps, let's see what we know about this story.

Now Adam knew Eve his wife, and she conceived and bore Cain, and said, “I have acquired a man from the Lord.” Then she bore again, this time his brother Abel. Now Abel was a keeper of sheep, but Cain was a tiller of the ground. (Genesis 4:1-2)

Note that there is actually a remark from Eve about her firstborn, and Abel is basically a footnote. So Cain is special, the firstborn human and firstborn for Eve. And she is grateful to God for Cain, but there is no joyous remark, no gratitude, no maternal pride accompanying Abel's birth.
The next thing we notice is that Cain is a farmer. In ancient cultures the first-born son inherited the land tilled by their father, and any other sons had to "make do" with whatever they could pull off. So Cain gets the farming area that Adam had worked on previously. And Abel has to go be clever and figure out something else. (There is a reason for why you don't divide land equally among children in ancient times, but that's not important right now)
So Abel is the one who has to become "the first" at something new. And he does. He tends to sheep, without any shortcut or advice he tends to sheep. It is also worth noting that a farm is not likely to "devour you" like predators would in the land with your sheep, or a storm or any other danger. So his profession is actually a dangerous one, because it is nomadic and his flock must also go with him everywhere he does. Where as Cain actually has a "home" where he can rest every night.
So it kinda sucks to be Abel. He suffers due to this reality. But he grows as a person instead of despairing. He learns skills and abilities that he uses to defend his flock of sheep and himself. We can see in other passages like 1 Samuel 17:36 where a good shepherd is a "slinger" who defends his sheep from lions and bears.
So Cain gets the "softer" life and Abel gets the "hard" life. How does that affect them as people? Well, Cain has this safe space near home, he does not have to be highly self-reliant or skillful in violent protection. And then you see Abel every so often, with his rapidly growing fortune (of sheep) and how he apparently has it "easy". And Abel is a good person. How frustrating is that? Cain is breaking his back every day making sure weeds and animals don't eat his crops... and abel just shows up with more sheep then he had a week ago. And no one cares about how many weeds you pulled do they?

And in the process of time it came to pass that Cain brought an offering of the fruit of the ground to the Lord. Abel also brought of the firstborn of his flock and of their fat. And the Lord respected Abel and his offering, but He did not respect Cain and his offering. And Cain was very angry, and his countenance fell. (Genesis 4:3-4)

So now we get to the sacrifice. What is it exactly? It isn't some superstitious practice of primitives. What is sacrifice? It is when you want to make things better in the future. Even in modern times this is how things are accomplished, you must sacrifice something in the present to improve the future in same way. We have the knowledge of the possibility of tragedy and suffering in the future, and this motivates us to sacrifice in the present, so we can reduce unnecessary anxiety, uncertainty and pain that awaits us. Old sacrifices are literally the same thing, just in a different way.

So my answer is "To sacrifice is human", and to sacrifice for the sake of the greater good is to act with human wisdom.

I am so grateful to you this answered my questions perfectly! Thank you!

Yes, all the 10 Commandments are expressions of the natural law written on our hearts (cf. Rom. 2:15). The First Commandment says that worshiping God (sacrificing to Him) is part of our nature.

Thank you! Does "the work of the law written in their hearts" mean that sacrificing for God is an instinctual action or something we all know is right deep down without being an inherent part of our nature?

@sofi Yes! You see that even in societies that had never heard of Christ (e.g., the Aztecs in Mexico before Hernando Cortes brought the Faith to them) sacrificed (albeit disorderedly with human sacrifice). It wasn't until they were taught the Faith that they understood the True God and that you can't violate the 5th Commandment ("Thou shalt not murder") in their attempt to sacrifice to who they mistakenly thought was the Supreme God.

Sacrifice is a voluntary impulse of love and gratitude to God. I would not say it is inherent, because not everyone offer a sacrifice to God. I would say, it is a grace from God, it is the connection of His Spirit and man. One great example of this is our Lord Jesus when He sacrifice Himself because of love.

( John 3:16
16 For God so loved the world, as to give his only begotten Son: that whosoever believeth in him may not perish, but may have life everlasting. ).

Sacrifice is the offering of the best of what you got even if it is only what you got like the obedience of Abraham to sacrifice Isaac. Because he love God with all his heart and might, he has to choose between God and Isaac.

Genesis 22:66  And he took the wood for the holocaust, and laid it upon Isaac his son; and he himself carried in his hands fire and a sword.

Sacrifice pleases God when we offer the best of our love for Him, like Abel.

(genesis 4:4
4 Abel also offered of the firstlings of his flock, and of their fat: and the Lord had respect to Abel, and to his offerings.)


It just means they were given instructions that aren't mentioned.

Eh, I think there is more to it then that. Also this could be a comment.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Without citation demonstrating your assertion, this is just a personal comment and not an answer to the question.
